# groupadd failure: "Cannot open audit interface"

Tags: debian, group, audit, debootstrap

I'm trying to add a group in a chrooted environment:

```
root@my-host:/# /usr/sbin/groupadd -g 101 games
Cannot open audit interface - aborting.
```

I'm operating with root permissions.

Additional info: this fails some package installation during debootstrap.

Comment: Is the chroot environment ok? `/dev /sys /proc` mounted etc.?

Comment: @jofel Not sure... /dev contains some devices. /sys and /proc are empty. How is it related?

Comment: Try to mount it (see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/165116/mount-dev-proc-sys-in-a-chroot-environment)). It could also be, that your kernel has no audit support (the source code has the comment `"You get these only when the kernel doesn't have audit compiled in."` before your error message is printed. [ [`libmisc/audit_helper.c`](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-shadow/shadow.git/tree/libmisc/audit_help.c#n61) )